# How to combine variables from a column in only one variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset from which I had faced the following situation:

```
df2['Shape'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

```
Round       0.561806
Princess    0.090057
Emerald     0.070318
Oval        0.070072
Radiant     0.058722
Pear        0.044658
Marquise    0.028374
Asscher     0.023933
Oval        0.015297
ROUND       0.013570
Cushion     0.009623
Marwuise    0.005922
Marquis     0.003948
Uncut       0.003701
Name: Shape, dtype: float64
```

My goal is to combine the simmilar variables from this column (e.g, Round and ROUND; Oval and Oval) in only one variable. How can I combine they?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to standardize the names. You can `lower` or `capitalize` the shape ids before running `value_counts`:

```
df2['Shape'].str.capitalize().value_counts(normalize=True)
```

output:

```
Round     0.575376
Princess  0.090057
Oval      0.085369
Emerald   0.070318
Radiant   0.058722
Pear      0.044658
Marquise  0.028374
Asscher   0.023933
Cushion   0.009623
Marwuise  0.005922
Marquis   0.003948
Uncut     0.003701
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, what about the 'Marquis', 'Marwuise' and 'Marquise' that are the same names but with typing errors? How standardize they?

Comment: This is more subjective. You probably need to know that those have the same meaning, and decide which one is the reference. I'd go with a dictionary of mappings: `maps = {'Marwuise': 'Marquise', 'Marquis': 'Marquise'} ; df2['Shape'].str.capitalize().map(maps)...`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are spaces on the right side of one of the "Oval" strings, then:

```
df['Shape'].str.capitalize().str.rstrip().value_counts(normalize=True)
```